# If employee is not present in system with the User system will create new employee and sync the details

Tags: trigger

this is my trigger code to insert new employee record if its not exist with user.but am getting below error.
 Error: Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: String,     Set ,help me to resolve..

```
trigger SyncUserToEmployee  on User (After insert, after update) {
SET<id> empid=new SET<id>();
list<Employee__c> insertemp=new list<Employee__c>();
for (user u:trigger.new)
{
empid.add(u.EmployeeNumber);
}
map<id,Employee__c> em=new map<id,Employee__c>([select id from Employee__c where id IN:empid]);
for(user u:trigger.new)
{
 if(u.EmployeeNumber!=empid)
{
Employee__c e =new Employee__c();
e.First_Name__c=u.Name;
e.Email__c=u.Email;
e.Phone_Number__c=u.Phone;

insertemp.add(e); 
 }
}
 insert insertemp;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is on this line:

```
if(u.EmployeeNumber!=empid)
```

The reason is that `u.EmployeeNumber` is a Text(20) field, and `empid` is a `Set<>` that you declared earlier:

```
SET<id> empid=new SET<id>();
```

To fix it you can change this set to a `String` set and then use `contains()` method instead of `==`:

```
if (!empid.contains(u.EmployeeNumber)) {
    // do your logic if this EmployeeNumber is not in this set
}
```

Comment: thank you @novag . now  its working but how can i synchronize new created employee  with user?..

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the error message that the field `EmployeeNumber` is a string, not an ID which makes sense. As such, this line:

```
SET<id> empid=new SET<id>();
```

needs to be changed to a string as follows:

```
SET<string> empid=new SET<string>();
```

A string will cast to an Id when you do the insert later.